# CORS error using axios and proxy MERN APP

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy, axios, mern

I made MERN app and I create two repositories. I deploy backend part on heroku. I try using my frontend part local using proxy :"proxy": "http://app-name-backend.herokuapp.com" all work perfect. But when I try to remove proxy and use axios method with full path like

```js
const config = {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "x-auth-token": `${token}`,
    },
};
    
const res = await axios.post(
    `http://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/api/event`,
    item,
    config
);
```

I get some error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) library installed? maybe it can help you.

Comment: Yes, I just need to install cors on the backend and use it